# Scrapy - one request needs recent output from other

Tags: scrapy

I have a spider for an API. The API works in a way that you call an URL, which gives you back an authorization token, that is valid for a few minutes to do API calls.

The problem I see now is that I do this call, and pass the token to all underlying requests, but when the token expires the requests start to fail.

What would be the best way to go about this? Ideally I'd just schedule the token request every minute and share the token as some kind of variable the request then use at the moment they are executed. But I think that's not possible.

Comment: Just have your spider recognize a failed request. When that occurs, call the function that acquires a new access token.

Comment: Do you still need a solution? I can provide you one.

Comment: I sort of have it working, but would be interested to know you're solution